# Owin OAuth vs OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

Generally OAuth definition says that it is way where user gives an application access to his resources stored in other application (without exposing the actual username and password). But inside Owin, it is a way to implement token based authentication within an application. Although we can deploy the Authorisation application at different server. But crux remains the same. Could anybody shed some light. I am very confused.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the OAuth 2.0 spec you will find this:

> The authorization process utilizes two authorization server
>   endpoints    (HTTP resources):
>
> o  Authorization endpoint - used by the client to obtain
>         authorization from the resource owner via user-agent redirection.
>
> o  Token endpoint - used by the client to exchange an authorization
>         grant for an access token, typically with client authentication.
>
> As well as one client endpoint:
>
> o  Redirection endpoint - used by the authorization server to
>   return
>         responses containing authorization credentials to the client via
>         the resource owner user-agent.
>
> Not every authorization grant type utilizes both endpoints.
>   Extension grant types MAY define additional endpoints as needed.

So basically, you have 2 options:
1) Use the authorization endpoint where your end-user is redirected to a form that is handled by the authorization server

OR

2) Create your own form inside your app, get the end-user credentials and send that data to the authorization server, where it will be validated and return a token for you to use.